# Is there a smoke alarm which can be hushed in DENSE smoke?

Tags: smoke-detectors

Every smoke alarm I've ever owned has a "hush" feature allowing you to push a button and stop a false alarm, for instance one caused by cooking. However, they all state a caveat in the owner's manual to the effect that dense smoke will override the hush feature, and continue sounding the alarm. Well, maybe I'm just an especially bad cook, but I don't think I have ever once in my life seen this hush feature actually work. I suppose I'm just always dealing with smoke that is dense enough to override the hush button. The only real solution is to take the smoke detector down and remove its batteries, which obviously is not safe, and I usually forget to put them back up in a timely manner.

So is there a smoke detector on the market which has a hush button that cannot be overridden by dense smoke, and just stops the alarm.

Comment: Turn off all your devices when you cook, or, don't leave the kitchen when you cook. Or be really fastidious about setting timers.  Or shift your cooking to appliances that have auto-shutoff.  I got a toaster oven with a timer and it's **so much better**!  You could also get an induction hot plate and have it on a rated plug-in timer.

Comment: Why are you generating so much cooking smoke? Is your existing alarm ionization or photoelectric?

Comment: burnt food can be carcinogenic ... you may wish to rethink your cooking style

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use a smoke alarm, but **do** use a temperature alarm known as “rate of rise”, these detect the change in temperature caused by a fire and are used in those possibly smoky areas such as kitchens.

Do check with fire and insurance.